# How can i put Text and image Widget together in my home screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

im working on a quotes app.So as my home screen appear,i wants an image in the background.And some text in fornt of that image.I managed to code app bar and home screen but cant stack both image and text widget together in my stateful widget class.Can you people please help me about it?(im a beginnier)

```
 class OverviewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _OverviewScreenState createState() => _OverviewScreenState();
 }

 class _OverviewScreenState extends State<OverviewScreen> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MaterialApp(
  home:Scaffold(
    extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
    appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Hu   R   Rehman",
        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "MonteCarlo"),),
        centerTitle: true,
      leading: Icon(Icons.menu),

      shape:RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(16))
      ),
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      elevation: 0,

    ),
    body: Center(
      child: Image(
        image:AssetImage('Image/soc1.jpg'),
        fit:BoxFit.cover,
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
      ),
      )
      ),
      );
      }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  return Container(
    child: Column(
  children: [
    Image(
      image: AssetImage('assets/images/hello.jpg'),
    ),
    Text('Hello world'),
  ],
));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try a `Container` with a `DecorationImage` and a `Text` as a child:

```dart
 return Center(
      child: Container(
        width:250,
        height:250,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('Image/soc1.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child:const Text('This is my text over image'),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: sorry but its not working.the app bar is gone.pic shrunk..text is showing.But all the problem happening too

Comment: This code shows ONLY the image+text part, not the whole app you want to have. If you want your photos to have standard dimensions, I have updated the answer check it.